# Spock test is failing on NullPointerException

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, service, spock

I am woking on a small grails application and started to use spock as a test framework.

The test is extremely simple at this point:

```
    @TestFor(TokenService)
class TokenServiceSpec extends Specification {

    TokenService tokenService = new TokenService()

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    def "test generateToken"() {
        expect: 
        tokenService.generateToken(5).length() == 5
    }
}
```

Where **generateToken** is an existing public method in **TokenService**.

When I execute the test I am getting:

```
Failure:  test generateToken(com.iibs.security.TokenServiceSpec)
|  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.iibs.security.TokenServiceSpec.test generateToken(TokenServiceSpec.groovy:22)
```

When I debug it, I can verify that **tokenService** is instantiated properly.
What could be a reason for this failure?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are writing a Unit Test Case, you need not to create the `TokenService` object using :-

```
TokenService tokenService = new TokenService()
```

Already an implicit `service` object is present there, which you can make use of like :-

```
    @TestFor(TokenService)
    class TokenServiceSpec extends Specification {

def setup() {
}

def cleanup() {
}

def "test generateToken"() {
    expect: 
    service.generateToken(5).length() == 5
   }
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much. However, I am still puzzled why it didn't work the original way. What actually stops me from create the object myself?

Comment: As services are singleton in grails, we should not try creating new instances of it, and as already `service` object is there, we can always make use of it :)